# How to access key outside of object in when condition of JOI?

Tags: node.js, joi

How to put the condition for the outside field from the `current` object,

I have `type` field valid values are "text" and "video",

- when `type: "text"` then `text` object is required of `content` object
- when `type: "video"` then `video` object is required of `content` object

```
// not working
{
    type: Joi.string().valid("text", "video").required(),
    content: Joi.object().keys({
        text: Joi.object().keys({
            body: Joi.string().required(),
            preview_url: Joi.boolean().required()
        }).when('type', {
            is: "text",
            then: Joi.required(),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
        }),

        video: Joi.object().keys({
            url: Joi.string().required()
        }).when('type', {
            is: "video",
            then: Joi.required(),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
        })
    })
}
```

When I remove `content` object and put `text` and `video` object outside then it works perfectly, as the below code is working,

```
// working
{
    type: Joi.string().valid("text", "video").required(),
    text: Joi.object().keys({
        body: Joi.string().required(),
        preview_url: Joi.boolean().required()
    }).when('type', {
        is: "text",
        then: Joi.required(),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    }),

    video: Joi.object().keys({
        url: Joi.string().required()
    }).when('type', {
        is: "video",
        then: Joi.required(),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this reference git issue's solution [issue-799](https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/799#issuecomment-218810782),

Just need to put when condition for `content` object,

```
{
    type: Joi.string().valid("text", "video").required(),
    content: Joi.object().keys({
        text: Joi.object().keys({
            body: Joi.string().required(),
            preview_url: Joi.boolean().required()
        }).forbidden(),
        video: Joi.object().keys({
            url: Joi.string().required()
        }).forbidden()
    }).required()
    .when('type', {
        is: "text",
        then: Joi.object({ text: Joi.required() })
    })
    .when('type', {
        is: "video",
        then: Joi.object({ video: Joi.required() })
    })
}
```